# Codewars: Solving Kata - Highest and Lowest

Tags: python

This should work but I'm getting errors when running the test cases. For some reason the fourth one fails. numbers[0] prints out '-1' but after assigning to highest_number or lowest_number only the '-' prints out. What gives?

Code:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    if numbers:
        highest_number = numbers[0]
        lowest_number = numbers[0]
        numbers = numbers.split(" ")
        print(highest_number)
        print(lowest_number)
        print(numbers[0])
        for num in numbers:
            if int(num) > int(highest_number):
                highest_number = num
            if int(num) < int(lowest_number):
                lowest_number = num
        return highest_number + " " + lowest_number
```

Test Cases:

```
Test.assert_equals(high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"), "542 -214");
Test.assert_equals(high_and_low("1 -1"), "1 -1");
Test.assert_equals(high_and_low("1 1"), "1 1");
Test.assert_equals(high_and_low("-1 -1"), "-1 -1");
Test.assert_equals(high_and_low("1 -1 0"), "1 -1");
Test.assert_equals(high_and_low("1 1 0"), "1 0");
Test.assert_equals(high_and_low("-1 -1 0"), "0 -1");
Test.assert_equals(high_and_low("42"), "42 42");
```

Error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your numbers first, else you are just assigning the first *character* of `numbers` to your variables:

```
    numbers = numbers.split(" ")
    highest_number = numbers[0]
    lowest_number = numbers[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here try this! I just got it, I feel so silly, you can add strings with the `+` sign!

Answer is:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
  # must split the numbers, convert them to integers and print the max and min of list
  numbers = numbers.split()
  numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]
  return str(max(numbers))+" "+str(min(numbers))
```